# Neo4j 3x and legacy node_auto_indexing with custom Lucene Analyzer

Tags: neo4j, lucene, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

In my Neo4j 3.0.3 and SDN 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT I have created a following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jTestConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    private static final String NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY = "neo4j.embedded.database.path";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Components.setDriver(new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService()));

        EmbeddedDriver embeddedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver();
        GraphDatabaseService databaseService = embeddedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService();
        try (Transaction t = databaseService.beginTx()) {
            Index<Node> autoIndex = databaseService.index().forNodes("node_auto_index");
            databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "type", "fulltext");
            databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "to_lower_case", "true");
            databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "analyzer", StandardAnalyzerV36.class.getName());
            t.success();
        }
    }

    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {

        // @formatter:off
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File(environment.getProperty(NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY)))       
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "name,description")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true").
                newGraphDatabase();         
        // @formatter:on        

        return graphDatabaseService;
    }
```

...

}

Also, I have implemented StandardAnalyzerV36:

```
public final class StandardAnalyzerV36 extends Analyzer {

    public static final CharArraySet STOP_WORDS_SET = StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET;  

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {

        final ClassicTokenizer src = new ClassicTokenizer();
        TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(src);
        tok = new StopFilter(new LowerCaseFilter(tok), STOP_WORDS_SET);

        return new TokenStreamComponents(src, tok);
    }

    @Override
    protected Reader initReader(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        return new HTMLStripCharFilter(reader);
    }   
...
}
```

Right now my test fails because of looks like `StandardAnalyzerV36` is not correctly applied to index.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

**UPDATED**

I'm trying to configure driver with `ogm.properties`:

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver

dbms.auto_index.nodes.keys=name,description
dbms.auto_index.nodes.enabled=true
```

and config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jTestConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        EmbeddedDriver embeddedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver();
        GraphDatabaseService databaseService = embeddedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService();

        try (Transaction t = databaseService.beginTx()) {
            Index<Node> autoIndex = databaseService.index().forNodes("node_auto_index");
            databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "type", "fulltext");
            databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "to_lower_case", "true");
            databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "analyzer", StandardAnalyzerV36.class.getName());
            t.success();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("com.example");
    }

}
```

but it still doesn't work.

What settings should be placed in `ogm.properties` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should create a new embedded driver: `Components.setDriver(new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService()));`

Instead, get the GraphDatabaseService from the already configured driver and use that?

```
     EmbeddedDriver embeddedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver();
     GraphDatabaseService databaseService = embeddedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService();
     try (Transaction t = databaseService.beginTx()) {
      Index<Node> autoIndex = databaseService.index().forNodes("node_auto_index");
      databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "type", "fulltext");
      databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "to_lower_case", "true");
      databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "analyzer", StandardAnalyzerV36.class.getName());
      t.success();
     }
```

If you want to configure the embedded driver programatically, then you can set it up like this in SDN

```
@Bean
public Configuration getConfiguration() {
   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config
       .driverConfiguration()
       .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver")
       .setURI("file:///var/tmp/graph.db");
   return config;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), <packages> );
}
```

or like this with only the OGM:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
             .driverConfiguration()
             .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver")
             .setURI(uri);
```

Then use the same method above to get a handle to the underlying graph database.

**Update**:
ogm.properties does not support dbms.auto_index.nodes.keys or dbms.auto_index.nodes.enabled. These are to be configured when creating the GraphDatabaseService, there is no way to do this with the current version of the OGM. See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/134

Comment: I have added `ogm.properties` in order to configure embedded drive without `Components.setDriver(new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService()));` but looks like `dbms.auto_index.nodes.keys`, `dbms.auto_index.nodes.keys` doesn't work this way. What am I doing  wrong ?